# What is the rationale for C++ switch only working for integral types?

Tags: c++, syntax, switch-statement

I feel that C++ should allow `switch()` over any type that can be compared, not just integral types. It seems odd that:

```
switch(myEnum)
{
    case myEnumValue1:
        ... break;
    case myEnumValue1:
        ... break;
}
```

Is semantically the same as:

```
if(myEnum == myEnumValue1)
    ...
else if(myEnum == myEnumValue2)
    ...
```

But this only works on integral types. Why? What is the purpose of such a restriction?

I understand that the compiler-generated code for `switch` may only be compatible with integral or register-sized types, but these kinds of things are normally black-boxed from the developers' decisions. These kinds of things are normally abstracted from us. If a jump table is better, the compiler should generate one. If a typical `if`/`else` algorithm is needed, so be it.

Comment: That question is talking about specific code, and the answers amount to "because switch only works on integral types", or my last paragraph. I'm looking for rationale.

Comment: In C it's not possible but in C++ you have operator overloading, so I think it's a good reason to add `switch case` ability to any object type to C++, as long as its `==` or `!=` operator is defined.

Comment: Extending the switch statement was proposed for C++0x in [n1741](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2004/n1741.pdf), but was not included. A weaker version was recently proposed again in [n3627](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3627.html). These documents (especially the first) provide a lot of insight into why this is not as easy as it might appear at first glance. (would have posted this as an answer with more details if the question hadn't been closed already)

Answer (score 0):

The switch statement was inherited from C, itself designed in the holy days when efficiency was still a concern. Yes, this is most probably because it allows "computed gotos", i.e. jump tables.

A sequence of compares can indeed be an alternative, but for long case lists, hashing could be preferred. Not in the scope of this early language.

Comment: I understand it was inherited, but C++ is a different language, more semantic, letting the compiler make decisions for you. Are we to believe that the answer is really just laziness? The designers just didn't pay attention to switch? IOW, "it was inherited" is not really an answer. Why wasn't it changed from C's behavior?

Comment: No, compatibility. C++ was not a different language. Early versions were just preprocessed C code.

Comment: This would not affect compatibility... I'm talking C++11/14

Comment: Certainly not laziness.